# Does Vietnamese mười reflects the Thai/Lao/Khmer uu sound?

Tags: thai, lao, vietnamese, sprachbund, khmer

When I was in Vietnam I tried to pronounce the word mười (10) with the Thai/Lao/Khmer `uu` sound:

**Thai:** ◌ู
**Lao:** [image]
**Khmer (ou):** ូ
**Khmer (uə):** ួ

I recognized that sometimes it worked and sometimes it didn't and at some point assumed that either it is indeed shared but I'm wrong somewhere else, or that the Vietnamese `uu` sound is a bit different than that of Thai/Lao/Khmer.

Does Vietnamese "uu" in mười reflects the Thai/Lao/Khmer `uu` sound or is it something similar but essentially different so that it doesn't exist in Thai/Lao/Khmer at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short answer

The Thai vowel อู is a **high, back, rounded** vowel.
The corresponding Lao vowel is very similar and for the Khmer one I can’t comment.

The first element of the Vietnamese diphthong in mười is the vowel ư,
 which is a **high, central, unrounded** vowel.

But
Vietnamese also has a vowel u, which is like อู is a **high back rounded** vowel.

#### Interim summary

The vowel ư in mười is essentially different from อู in that it is unrounded.
If anything, u would correspond to อู instead.

### Long answer (based on short answer)

The sample formant values shown in the below paint, indicate a slightly more complex picture:

> อู     u     ư

```
F1  1417.62           470                380

F2  918.76            760               1390

F3  2776.98          2690           2870
```

These values put อู somewhere between ư, and u, though quite a bit closer to u.
I think it's still fair to say that there is an essential difference between อู and ư, in that one is rounded and the other is not.
The take-away is really that อู is not exactly the same as u either.
On a practical level, if you use it in place of ư, it is likely to be heard as u, or at the very least, you will have a hard time making a distinction between ư and u.

---

Sources of the formant values (and the qualitative descriptions of the vowels):

<sub>**Thai:** Directly reported in Narang and Misra, Acoustic Space, Duration and Formant Patterns in vowels of Bangkok Thai, Language Processing 20(3) 123.</sub>

<sub>**Vietnamese:** Via Praat from the native-speaker examples in the pronunciation guide in Bin Nhu Ngo, Elementary Vietnamese, Tuttle 2015 (based on Hanoi Vietnamese).</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I would post this as a comment but I don't have the rep. If you look on YT you will find a series called Sawasdee Vietnam which teaches Vietnamese in Thai. You might find that helpful if you are interested in correspondences between the sounds (I think episode 2 goes through the vowels). I'm fairly sure ư gets equated with with อือ. I'm a lot less sure that's accurate, but it does tell you that Thai speakers aren't hearing อู. I don't think there's any lip-rounding going on in ư.